# Local to remote command not working

Tags: bash, ssh, sed

Trying to delete a zone file from a name server (remote) from a local machine (connecting to the remote server with a key pairing).

Script on the name server is below (remzone) which is executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i '/$1/,+4d' /etc/named.conf
rm -f /var/named/slaves/$1.db
rndc reload
echo "$1"
```

The local command I am running is.....

```
ssh root@server '~/remzone domain.com'
```

When I run the command locally, the following output is provided.

```
me@Main:~$ ssh root@server '~/remzone domain.com'
server reload successful
domain.com
```

When executing the command locally, the domain.com.db is removed from /var/named but it does not remove the matching line (+4 lines) from /etc/named.conf.

```
Zone    "domain.com" IN {
        type slave;
        masters {XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;};
        file "slaves/domain.com.db";
};
```

When I run `sed -i '/domain.com/,+4d' /etc/named.conf` on the nameserver directly, it deletes the zone file correctly from the `/etc/named.conf` file.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Your shellscript has incorrect quoting on two lines.  Whenever you have a shell script error, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages, then come here and ask.

Comment: Changed the script (remzone) on the remote server from `sed -i '/$1/,+4d' /etc/named.conf` to `sed -i "/$1/,+4d" /etc/named.conf` AND `rm -f /var/named/slaves/$1.db` to `rm -f /var/named/slaves/"$1".db`.  That corrected the issue.  @John1024 Thank you very much for the assistance and [https://www.shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net).  I did not know that site was around.